# OpenEJB unit test exclude or include package

Tags: unit-testing, openejb

I'm using OpenEJB to unit test EJBs which basically works fine.

The Maven module however contains a lot of EJBs of which one of them fails under test which cannot easily be fixed, so I would like to exclude that EJB or even better, include only the EJB that I want to test.

I am aware of the the properties `openejb.deployments.classpath.exclude` and `openejb.deployments.classpath.include`, but they don't help here since all EJBs are in the same classpath `module/target/classes`.

The [documentation](http://tomee.apache.org/properties-listing.html) also mentions the properties `openejb.deployments.package.exclude` and `openejb.deployments.package.include`, but they don't seem to have any effect. For example, I tried

```
System.setProperty("openejb.deployments.package.exclude", ".*");
System.setProperty("openejb.deployments.package.include", "");
```

which should exclude all and include no packages, but still all packages are included.

I also tried scan.xml but it seemed to be ignored, too:

> scan.xml: in META-INF or WEB-INF it lists the classes/packages to
>   scan. here is a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<scan>
 <packages>
  <package>org.foo1</package>
  <package>org.foo2</package>
 </packages>
 <classes>
  <class>org.bar.Bar1</class>
  <class>org.anotherbar.Bar2</class>
 </classes>
</scan>
```

Is there any other way to include/exclude packages or classes?